# Is there Lambda support in QML files?

Tags: javascript, lambda, qml, qtquick2

I have something like this:

```
var arr = []
arr.indexOf(element => element.includes(''))
```

QtCreator gives error for this. My Qt version is 5.12 and I'm using QtCreator 4.8.

Can I use this kind of lambda expressions in QML?

Comment: First of all, the method called [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), not `indexOf` if we talk about lambdas. But anyway, `findIndex` doesn't supported in ECMAScript subset of `QML`. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ecmascript.html) for full list of supported functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was just a QtCreator bug, arrow functions are supported in Qt 5.12 and later. QtCreator properly supports them starting 4.9 version and stop displaying warnings for it ([QTCREATORBUG-21301](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-21301) & [QTCREATORBUG-20341](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20341). See [4.9 changelog](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/dist/changes-4.9.0.md?h=4.9)).

In your case however, as folibis said, you need `findIndex` if you want to provide a predicate. It does work in 5.12, the page of the supported functions is not very reliable.

Qt 5.12 should support most of the standard ECMAScript functions, look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for reference and try it your Qt code.

```
{
    let arr = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd'];
    let index = arr.findIndex(element => element.includes('c'));
    let abcIsPresent = arr.includes('abc');
    print(index, abcIsPresent);
}
```

This codes runs in Qt 5.12 and outputs `2 true`.